# Are there any blockchain explorers that provide raw Tx data and block headers?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, raw-data, block-header

I've looked at some of the more popular blockchain explorers, but none of them seem to provide the feature I'm looking for. I'd like to find a blockchain explorer that allows you to see raw Tx data and raw block headers. The explorer's I've seen parse the raw data and present it in a more human readable format. Are there any that provide the raw data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get this info from blockchain.info, by simply adding `?format=hex`to the end of the relevant URL.

For example, here is a recent block (height 509,244):

https://blockchain.info/block/0000000000000000000635bda771916ca727db53fea5441508f7161386e066be

And here is the raw data for that block, in hex:

https://blockchain.info/block/0000000000000000000635bda771916ca727db53fea5441508f7161386e066be?format=hex

(Note that you will need to parse the block header out of this data, as that URL will dump the raw data for the entire block)

Similarly, here is a transaction from that block:

https://blockchain.info/tx/74d350ca44c324f4643274b98801f9a023b2b8b72e8e895879fd9070a68f7f1f

And here is the raw data from that transaction, in hex

https://blockchain.info/tx/74d350ca44c324f4643274b98801f9a023b2b8b72e8e895879fd9070a68f7f1f?format=hex

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about this! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you happen to know the URL for testnet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [insight](https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api) by bitpay:

```
/insight-api/rawblock/[:blockHash]
/insight-api/rawblock/[:blockHeight]
/insight-api/rawtx/[:rawid]
```

Comment: This is also a great option, only accepting the other answer because it's more in line with what I was looking for, AKA online block explorer with that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Updated for October 2021: blockchain.info (now blockchain.com) doesn't give raw data back just from appending `?format=hex` to its usual explorer anymore. Rather, you have to use their API, which they document here: https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_api

I couldn't get this to work in my browser, but at the terminal this worked for me:

```
% wget -O block154595.blk "https://blockchain.info/rawblock/0000000000000bae09a7a393a8acded75aa67e46cb81f7acaa5ad94f9eacd103?format=hex"
```